# Python - Request check?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
POSTURL = 'https://partner.spreadshirt.de/login'
REQURL = 'https://partner.spreadshirt.de/dashboard'
payload = {
    "username": 'test@gmail.com',
    "password": 'somepassword'
}
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POSTURL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQURL)
    print("String" in r.text)
```

I know that this String is in present on the Website so this is not the problem. But my code returns False, so maybe I cant get to the REQURL? How could I determine if I got there?

Comment: check the HTTP status code: r.status_code

Comment: Its 200, but even if I put a wrong pwd in there the Code is 200